# C# Facebook API : Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

in a windows application (using C#), I am trying to get the facebook likes using Facebook graph API.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("<token here>");
dynamic pageLikes = fb.Get("/wotif/insights/page_fans_country");
Console.WriteLine("" + pageLikes.data.ToString());
```

The above works fine !
I want to extract the likes until a date.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("<token here>");
dynamic pageLikes = fb.Get("/wotif/insights/page_fans_country?until=1391244171");
```

However the above is throwing error. I tried various dateformats but with no success.

this is the error I get (checked this in graph API explorer)..

```
{ "error": { "message": "(#100) Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 } }
```

Please help. thanks

Comment: this is the error I get (checked this in graph API explorer)..      {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Comment: `edit` your answer, it's way better than adding comments here